# Using picasso inside a NavigationView

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to use picasso in an Activity and using a NavigationView(for a Drawer).

Here is the latest of what I have.

```html
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_main_search_layout);
        final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_main_search);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        userEmail = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_email);
        profilePic = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_drawer);

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            userEmail.setText(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            uuid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            Log.d(TAG, "email_test_log: " + auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

            storageRef.child(uuid + "/profile_pic/main.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                    Log.d(TAG, "TEST_PIC_LOC: "+ uri);
                    Picasso.with(navigationView.getHeaderView(0).getContext()).load(uri).into(profilePic);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            });
        }
        showFragment(new SearchFragment());
    }
```

The error is with this line

`(Picasso.with(navigationView.getHeaderView(0).getContext()).load(uri).into(profilePic);)`

The error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

I have tried different variations such as "this", but doesn't compile, "getContext", "getApplication" but the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two possibility for this error one is Resource id is null or Your context may be null.

CheckYour Resource ID:

```
R.id.profile_pic_drawer // check this available or not
```

Second is Your activity context pass like this :

```
Picasso.with(YourActivityName.this).load(uri).into(profilePic);
```

Still getting error just show me the code i will help you.

Comment: It was the assignment of the resource id.I had profilePic = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_drawer) and it should of been profilePic = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_drawer);

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
 profilePic = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_drawer);
 Picasso.with(navigationView.getHeaderView(0).getContext()).load(uri).into(profilePic);
```

by:

```
profilePic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_drawer);
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).into(profilePic);
```

Or check your uri value, may be it null

Comment: Actually that works, but the main issue was with the imageview assignment. See comment above.

Comment: i sure your problem is `profilePic`, check this available or not. Maybe it wrong id or wrong xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Picasso.with(getAplicationContext()).load(uri).into(profilePic);`